# c# Azure EntityFramework SQL Server database error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, azure

In VS2013 I have created an Asp.net WebAPI project that saves/retrieves data into an SQL Server database using the EntityFramework. The SQL Server database is hosted in Azure.

I have a Controller class that does this in my Web API project and it all works fine ... until I Publish my WebAPI project to Azure then I get this an error:

```
InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException. Message=Invalid object name 'dbo.MyTableName'.
```

It's important to note that this is working fine when I run the WebAPI project using Localhost.

Does anyone know how I can investigate what the problem is? I have attached to the debugger and put a break point. I can see it's failing on this line:

```
db.MyTableName.Find(id);
```

When I return a hardcoded value it works fine so it's clearly a problem connecting to the database using the EntityFramwork.
My hunch was that the reference path to the Model objects of the EntityFramework was incorrect after uploading to Azure. In web.config:
metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl...

I tried metadata=res://MyAssemblyName/Model1.csdl...

I tried metadata=res://MyAssemblyName.dll/Model1.csdl...

but still there is same error. Any other variations I can try here?

I have also updated to the SQL Server/azure FIREWall to make sure the correct IP Address was allowed but that wasn't the issue either.

Any ideas?

EDIT
I have also tried these connection strings with no luck

```
connectionString="metadata=res://AssemblyName/Model1.csdl|res://AssemblyName/Model1.ssdl|res://AssemblyName/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dev_db;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dev_db;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

Comment: Have you updated your connection string to use SQL Azure?  How did you attach a debugger to your webapi deployed in Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was happening was the connection string was automatically changed during Publishing the code to Azure. So I had to edit the web.config file on the Azure server and restart the website and it worked

Answer (score 0):

For Azure SQL, your Entity connection string should look like:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/xxxDataModel.csdl|res://*/xxxDataModel.ssdl|res://*/xxxDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxx.database.windows.net;initial catalog=xxxData;User Id=xxx;password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

Comment: I tried that but it's still not working. I updated the question with some other connection string I tried